# Solutions to the equation $-x^3\sin^2x-x\sin^2x+x^3\cos^2x+x\cos^2x+\cos x\sin x-x^2\cos x\sin x=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$-x^3\sin^2x-x\sin^2x+x^3\cos^2x+x\cos^2x+\cos x\sin x-x^2\cos x\sin x=0$$

I simplified the equation to

$$x(x^2+1)(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)=(x^2-1)\cos x\sin x.$$

I got numerical solutions from Wolfram Alpha but I was wondering if there is a way to find solutions algebraically.

Comment: Try using the double angle formulas, and/or maybe the Weierstrass angle identities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought when you said this was to transform your last equation into the following using double angle formulas:

$$x(x^2+1)\cos(2x)=(x^2-1)\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$$

$$\Rightarrow \tan(2x)=\frac{2x(x^2+1)}{x^2-1}$$

At this point, I'm gonna give you a piece of advice that's really helpful to know when dealing with problems like this. Polynomial equations? $P(x)=Q(x)$ with $P(x),Q(x)$ polynomials? Keeping the degrees pretty low, and there are some good methods to solve these. Trigonometric equations, only involving $\sin ,\cos,\tan,$ and their combinations? Even when you square them or add compound angles, these are still manageable.

However, when you mix these, they become REALLY sketchy, and overall very VERY rarely have nice, analytic solutions. Even the following MOST BASIC example doesn't have a simple solution.

$$x=\cos(x)$$

This number is called Dottie's number, and can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions. Forget about squaring these, adding double angles, rational functions and higher powers of $x$.

So...... there could be a solution, but I don't see it happening. The comment suggests Weierstrass substitution, which doesn't work with both trig and polynomial functions. Hopefully that tip helps you in general though. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

@Luna145 already gave the most important information.

In principle, the problem requires numerical methods but, with a bit of algebra, we can generate quite reasonable *approximations*.

Consider that you are looking for the non trivial zero's (there is an infinite number of them) of function
$$f(x)=2x(x^2+1)\cos(2x)-(x^2-1)\sin(2x)$$

Use Taylor series around $x=0$ and obtain
$$f(x)=4x \left(1-\frac{4 }{3}x^2-\frac{4 }{15}x^4+\frac{68 }{315}x^6-\frac{14
   }{405}x^8\right)+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$ and , stopping at this level of exapnsion, you see that inside parentheses you face a polynomial of degree $4$ in $y=x^2$; this can be solved with radicals.

Using the terms one at the time, the successive approximations of $y$ are then (I just give their numerical values)
$$\{0.750000,0.662278,0.707237,0.701214\}$$ while the "exact" solution, obtained using Newton method is $y=0.701520$. Then $x$.